# Does debug information get stripped from library on optimized build?

Tags: c, build, embedded

I am using GCC's C compiler for ARM. I've compiled Newlib using the C compiler. I went into the makefile for Newlib and, saw that the Newlib library gets compiled using -g -O2.

When compiling my code and linking against Newlib's standard C library does this debug information get stripped?

Comment: "optimized build" can mean many different things.  Sometimes it will include `-s` to strip debugging symbols (or not) ... or the output object(s) will be run through the `strip` command (or not).  It depends on the project, but you can always add these to your build process manually by adding -s to $LDFLAGS , or using strip on the command line (or a script)

Answer (score 1):

You can use -g and -O2 both together. The compiler with optimize the code *and* keep the debugging information. Of course at some places because of code optimization you will not get information for some symbol that has been removed by code optimization and is no longer present.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Gcc options summary](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html)

> Turning on optimization flags makes the compiler attempt to improve the performance and/or code size at the expense of compilation time and possibly the ability to debug the program.

There are multiple flags and options that will make debugging impossible or difficult. e.g.

> -fomit-frame-pointer .... It also makes debugging impossible on some machines.
>
> -fsplit-wide-types.... This normally generates better code for those types, but may make debugging more difficult.
>
> -fweb - ... It can, however, make debugging impossible, since variables no longer stay in a “home register”.

The first two are enabled for `-O2`.

If you want debugging information to be preserved, the following option can be used.

> -Og
>
> Optimize debugging experience. -Og enables optimizations that do not interfere with debugging. It should be the optimization level of choice for the standard edit-compile-debug cycle, offering a reasonable level of optimization while maintaining fast compilation and a good debugging experience.